# Sufficient Conditions for Finiteness of a Module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

In order to prove that a module is finite we can find a finite set of generators, or an exact sequence in which flanking terms are finite; or use Nakayama's lemma to drive a contradiction . I'm curious if there is any other ( general) condition that implies the finiteness of a module( over a noetherian ring).

Comment: you can try to embed your module in some non-obvious way into a module that is known to be finitely generated. Of course this only works if your ring is Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks for comments but embedding is  a special case of the exact sequence (mentioned above) A->B->C with A and B finite 

Comment: Ultimately, any proof must show the existence of ("find") a finite set of generators, so you could say that everything is a special case of this argument. I do not know what kind of answers you want, and judging from the lack of answers, others don't either.